# How can I see all the data of an in ipython conveniently?

Tags: data-visualization

Recently I moved from Matlab to python.

In Matlab, it is very convenient to check all the data content.

But in ipython, it is not the case. Besides using `print()` and saving to text file, is there any plugin or whatever that could check data the same way as Matlab's "Variable Bar"?

Sorry, I didn't make it clear. When the array size was large, `print()` or `vars()`,`locals()` mentioned by Baruchel would truncate the array like this even if there were non-zero values in the array:

```
'region': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    ..., 
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]])
```

I searched and know that by setting the 'threshold' parameter to 'nan' would make `print()` print all the data out.

I am looking for something that will show the index and content in array without truncating. If there weren't any then I'll settle for `print()` or `np.savetxt()`. Just a little inconvenient.

Thanks for your time, Baruchel and Solo. I learned something new, but the magic command `%who` seems preferable to `dir()` for my purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spyder Python IDE has a MATLAB-like interface, including a variable explorer.

Comment: Thanks. I just fount it too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dir() function.
A nice post about the functionality: [How to print all variables values when debugging Python with pdb, without specifying each variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961693/how-to-print-all-variables-values-when-debugging-python-with-pdb-without-specif)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `vars()`  or `locals()` functions but the output isn't really nice.